# Why is my post not give data to my controller from my form?

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp, spring-mvc

I am developing a Sprin MVC application and I have a form containing a table in one of the UI jsp's, (welcome.jsp) and when the submit button is clicked, I am trying to print out the data in the form to the web applications console.From there i intend to parse the checkboxes that are selected and then have the controller send the 'selected' data back to the databased to be updated to the next status in the applications flow.

So far the form is 'successfully' posting as in no error or exceptions is being thrown, but the printed statement in the console is blank which makes me think that no data is being sent, and I would greatly welcome any help to fix this.

Here is the setup of what I have, not the actual code but a rough set up of the elements and methods.

welcome.jsp:

```
   <form action="<c:url value="/postPage" />"method="post" modelAttribute="rTable">
       <br/>
       <table>
           <thead>
               <tr>
                   <th>title1</th>
                   <th>title2</th>
                   <th>title3</th>
                   <th><select>
                        <option>option1</option>
                        <option>option2</option>
                   </select></th>  
               </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
               <tr>
                   <td>value1</td>
                   <td>value1</td>
                   <td>value1</td>
                   <td><input type="checkbox" value="row_data_id" /></td>
               </tr>
           </tbody>
           <tfoot>
               <tr><td colspan="4"></td>
           </tfoot>
        </table>
        <br/>
    </form>
```

My controller has the following method in it with all the necessary libraries imported:

controller.java

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/postPage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processUpdate(@ModelAttribute("rTable") String table, ModelMap model) {
        System.out.println(table);
        return "postPage";

    }
```

The console line that is print is this:

```
    .
    .
    .
    [3/19/14 16:36:53:625 EDT] 0000006a SystemOut     O 
    .
    .
    .
```

Does anyone know why this is not printing anything? Am I really not successfully sending anything to the controller?

Comment: What value do you expect `table` to have? There are some serious things you don't seem to understand here: how do you submit forms and how are they submitted, what are request parameters, what is a `@ModelAttribute`, the difference between HTML's `form` and Spring's `<form>` tag lib.

Comment: I expected table to hold the current state of the table when the submit button is pushed. I am new to this so if I am getting this wrong then please bare with me. The table in the form is populated using a bean with necessary data and JSTL tags. The user is suppose to select check boxes and then click submit. From the submit I want to grab the data associated with the checkboxes and pass it back to the a bean or the controller so it can be used to update the database. I thought that is what I was doing but I guess not. Any tips, guides, or help of any kind would be awesome.

Comment: After reviewing things with others. I have found determined this in addition to what i has said before. Each checkbox in the form will have an Id associated with it.  That id uniquely corresponds to the data in the its row. I need to understand how to get the value of the select box in the title row and the id values of the selected checkboxes to the controller to be sent to update the database via jdbc or hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good deal of reading and trial and error I found my answer. I will explain in terms with spring framework forms. In order to pass data through the form from front-end to back end, first every input will need to be tied to the form using the spring form JSTL tag

ex.

form => form:form

input=> form:input

in the form:form it isn;t necessary but you should have a modelAttribute that is linked to a java class, then in each input their need to be a path attribute the is linked to a variable in the modelAttribute class and a value to assign to the variable. Then on a submit the values are linked to the back end via the getters and setters on the java class to be used in the back-end. I hope I am explained that clearly.